# Is it possible to record from a MIDI keyboard to audacity?

Tags: sound, keyboard

I am trying to make it so that I can record from audacity using a MIDI keyboard. Normally I use Qjackctl ,Zynaddsubfx and Ardour. The problem that I run into is exporting to an MP3. In an earlier question I learned how to import it from Ardour, but I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this. Can I simply record from my MIDI keyboard to Audacity? Thank you all again for your help, your knowledge and generosity are invaluable.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. A MIDI event does not make a sound all by itself, you need something like zynaddsubfx or fluidsynth to synthesize an instrument. Is your MIDI keyboard also a synthesizer, ie. can it make sounds without a computer?

Comment: No. I don't mind using zynaddsubfx, it is an awesome synth. If I use it is it possible to record into Audacity with it?